# Incrementally select values from SQL Server column, and set each value equal to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that is not going to change, unless I change it, and I would like to use it as a reference for variable values. I would like to take each row, in a column, and set the row to variable, execute a few commands, and then set the next row to the same variable, and repeat.

Ex.

Table with `rowNumber` and `RowValue` columns

```
declare @rowNumber int, @RowValue nvarchar(255)
set @rowNumber = 1

set @RowValue = (Row # in RowValue column)

execute instructions with @RowValue value.

set @rowNumber = @rowNumber + 1

loop
```

I know that I can use the instruction below to organize a row column, but I am not sure how to accomplish my task with assigning individual cell values to a variable.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY Names ) AS 'rownumber',*
FROM [Database Names]
```

Here is an example of the answer I was looking for, it involved using cursors to iteratively select values from a table collumn.

```
declare @DBName varchar(255)

declare db_cursor Cursor FOR 
select DBTable
from Database_Names.dbo.Database_Names
--where name not in ('DB') --Not Used but could be used to filter results

open db_cursor
Fetch Next from db_cursor into @DBName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       print  'The Database Selected is ' + @DBName

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DBName   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: Come again?  Do you want to set the value of a variable to a value from a row?  Then execute some TQL and repeat?  "Set the row to a variable" is a bit perplexing.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER takes exactly 0 arguments. What is the 2 in ROW_NUMBER(2)  supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry the "ROW_NUMBER(2)", was a typo that I forgot to remove. Sorry for the confusing nature of the question, but I am trying to read each cell in a column, one at a time, and assign that individual cell in row number 1 to a variable, the variable will be used as a name to create a database, and then the next cell value down a row in the column will be set to the variable and used to create a database. This will continue happening until there is a null value in the collumn.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create an identity on the table and use the ID to update the values of each row to each variable that you want to change. IE update table set variable_Value = '@x' where Variable_id = @VariableID. Then in your Loop set @VariableID = @VariableID +1 ? I might not understand the question fully, but this what it seems like you're trying to do.

Comment: The identity column sounds like it would be a good idea, and I understand the logic for incrementing the @VariableID, but how do you assign each Variable_ID to a specific variable_Value in the Database Table?

Comment: The answer to my question is to use Cursors to iteratively select values from a table collumn or collumns. I have edited my my post above to include an example.